# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED. Unhandled 'error' event NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am encountering the Nodejs error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 when I try to send a get request to load a static file. I have seen many questions on this error but apparently there is no straight answer as to why this error is thrown. Here below is the code I have. I have tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 or change port numbers 3000, 7000, 8080 but nothing resolved it. Can someone please advised? Thank you.

```
//Basic web client retrieving content of file using get request

var http = require('http');

//options for request 

var options = {

hostname: 'localhost',
port: '3000',
path: '../html/hello.html'

};

//function to handle response from request

  function getResponse(response){

  var serverData='';

  response.on('data', function(chunk){

     serverData += chunk;
  });

   response.on('end', function(){

      console.log(serverData);
   });
 };

  http.request(options, function(response, error){

  getResponse(response);

}).end();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your client code is good enough to work. You are getting the ECONNREFUSED because there is a no server which is listening to the particular port number and the Server is not sending any data and you are requesting to get data from the server and accumulate it.

Here is the sample code:

```
//Requesting for http and fs modules
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

//creating the server and reading the file synchronously
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('./html1.html'));
}).listen(3000);

//creating the client which connects to local host at port number 3000
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: '3000',
}

//getting the data from server, storing it in to a variable, and printing at end of the data
function getResponse(response){
    var serverData='';
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
            serverData += chunk;
    });
response.on('end', function(){
            console.log(serverData);
    });
};

http.request(options, function(response, error){
    getResponse(response);
}).end();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Unfortunately the ressource I am using to learn Node failed to point that a server needs to be up and running beforehand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue in your code , that you are not handling error, for this you have to handle error first.

```
var http = require('http');
    var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: '3000',
    path: '../html/hello.html'
    };
      function getResponse(response){
    var serverData='';

      response.on('data', function(chunk){
         serverData += chunk;
      });

       response.on('end', function(){
    console.log(serverData);
       });
     };

      http.request(options, function(error , response){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);//handle error here.
    }else{
      getResponse(response);
    }}).end();
```

Comment: It says that the error event is not handled, but even when I handle the error as you said, i still have the same error message and the ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 is still there.

Comment: may be the problem was another instance was running. run this command on your terminal 'netstat -tulpn' and after that check the port no and kill the process . i.e kill process_id. It should resume properly after.

Comment: With a command ps aux | grep node it shows no node instance running to kill. Which means that the error is not related to a running instance of node. @Shekar Tyagi I will absolutely upvote as soon as it works!

Comment: I am on Mac OS and it returns netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol